# Should CORS be disabled?

Tags: security, mobile, spring-security, cors

I have a backend server and I configured CORS filter to allow my frontend server to access backend public api. Now I want start developing mobile app, which also will communicate with backend server, but I can't simply put all origins in my cors filter. Should I set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * ? If so, will it be secure enough ? I don't keep user sessions, but with every request users send jwt token.

Comment: What do you mean, all origins are so many? the origins do not mean the client instances but the servers from which the scripts accessing the server are loaded

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing your own mobile app, then you will not need to have to change any CORS setting in your backend. Setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to wildcard i.e `*` will make it very unsafe as all sites will be able access public APIs from your site. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is used by different browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, Opera etc to verify if the frontend accessing the API from the backend is allowed to access the content. This is check only takes place if your APIs and your frontend are on two different domains or subdomains. Eg `foo.com` frontend is trying to access content from `bar.com` then your backend `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` needs to be set to `foo.com`.